# How long does it take DynamoDB to stop throttling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, throttling

Suppose I make a very large number of write requests to a DDB table, so that its provisioned write capacity is far exceeded and it starts to throttle me. I eventually stop sending requests. How long do I then have to wait before it's guaranteed that DDB will not throttle a new write request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB throttled on a per-second basis. If you have no retries enabled on your client, and you stop writing, you would be able to succeed in the following second.

However, when you have retries, those are still consuming capacity. So ultimately the answer is variable, depending on your retry and back-off strategy.

Retries would not surpass 1-2 minutes usually, if using the default configuration.

To further elaborate, capacity in DynamoDB is provisioned on a per-second basis. If you provision 100 RCU, you can consume 100 RCU per second. If you exceed 100 RCU in a given second, you get throttled. However, the following second still has 100 RCU available to you.

This is a simplified example, in reality DynamoDB is an extremely large distributed system, and counting every tables request rate synchronously would impact its performance. For that, we introduce the aspect of token buckets controlled by a PID controller. If you would like to learn more of how this works in-depth, then I suggest this video from [Jaso's re:Invent talk 2018](https://youtu.be/yvBR71D0nAQ?t=1599&si=OfA6KCN0-5KPMbJf)

Comment: Interesting answer! 'DynamoDB throttles on a per-second basis.' - do you have any confirmation of this in the official docs? I had the same question years ago and was never able to find an official confirmation.

Comment: None that explicitly states it. But by reading the docs, it's implicitly stated. Your capacity is provisioned by WCU or RCU. That's a limit of how much you can consume per second. So if you exceed the capacity in second 1, and you stop processing, in second 2 you will have the capacity that you provisioned. Throttling is simply an exception to state you've exceeded that seconds provisioned capacity.

Comment: Thank you! It'd be good to add what's in your comment to the answer to provide extra context.

Comment: Updated, if you're interested please give the entire re:Invent video a watch. It goes into great depths on what was previously regarded as implementation detail.